# Java compile error, sending properties in a method call

Tags: java, properties

I made some changes to the original code.  I still have to account for if the properties not loading though. Hopefully this will work.

public class AnalyzerDriver {

```
    private List<Analyzer> analyzers = new ArrayList<Analyzer>();
    private Map<String, Integer> tokenCounts;
    private Properties properties;

    public AnalyzerDriver() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnalyzerDriver analyzerDriver = new AnalyzerDriver();
        analyzerDriver.loadProperties();

        // these three lines are causing the error
        analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new SummaryReport(properties));
        analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new UniqueTokenAnalyzer(properties));
        analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new BigWordAnalyzer(properties));

    }

    public void loadProperties() {
        properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config/analyzer.properties"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Can't load the properties file");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public class SummaryReport implements Analyzer {

    private int totalTokensCount;
    private Properties properties;

    public SummaryReport() {
    }

    public SummaryReport(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

//changes

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    AnalyzerDriver analyzerDriver = new AnalyzerDriver();
    analyzerDriver.loadProperties();
    analyzerDriver.addAnalyzer();


}

public void addAnalyzer() {

    analyzers.add(new SummaryReport(properties));
    analyzers.add(new UniqueTokenAnalyzer(properties));
    analyzers.add(new BigWordAnalyzer(properties));

}

public void loadProperties()  {
    properties = new Properties();
    try {
       properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config/analyzer.properties"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Can't load the properties file");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: note that printing out the exact error you're receiving would expedite the speed at which your question would be answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `main` method is referring directly to the instance property `properties`

One solution would be to have the `properties` variable be local to `main` and passed directly to the `Analyzer` implementations. If it's not used anywhere else in the `AnalyzerDriver`, just return the properties from `loadProperties` and save to a local.

You'd need to decide what to do in case the properties fail to load (which you're not doing now).

```
... main(...) {
    Properties properties = loadProperties();
    analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new SummaryReport(properties));
    ....
```

*Edit* I removed the solution Usman is referring to, having a getter to return the instance's `properties`... property.

```
analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new SummaryReport(analyzerDriver.getProperties()));
```

Comment: @jeff In other words, the method call should be     analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new SummaryReport(analyzerDriver.properties)); or better analyzerDriver.analyzers.add(new SummaryReport(analyzerDriver.getProperties()));

Comment: @UsmanSaleem I edited that solution out from under you ;) But yep, a getter would be another option. In this case it's probably adequate to use a local, but you're right, I should have left that solution in!

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple problems.

`main()` is a static method; it can't access any non-static variables of the `AnalyzerDriver` class. `properties` is a private instance variable.

After that, you're trying to access a private instance variable (`analyzers`) from outside the instance (`analyzerDriver`) to add your drivers.

You probably want to create a public method in `analyzerDriver` to add `Analyzer` instances.

```
public void addAnalyzer(Analyzer a) 
{ 
    analyzers.add(a);
}
```

But that still leaves the problem of your properties. It really depends on your design and what you're doing but I'd probably implement an AnalyzerFactory (Factory pattern) that loaded the properties and then instantiated your Analyzer objects for you:

```
AnalyzerFactory factory = new AnaylyzerFactory();
Analyzer a = factory.get("SummaryReport");
analyzerDriver.addAnalyzer(a);
```